# django complex query hits db twice, although paginated.

Tags: django, pagination

I have a complex query that takes 3-4 seconds to be executed (can't go less, it as optimized as it can be). This is paginated. However, using django-debug-toolbar I noticed that database is 'hit' twice.

the first 'hit' is here: `items = paginator.page(page_number)` and then a bit later at `if items:`

Although query takes 3-4 seconds. Hitting database in those two points I get an estimated page load of 6-7 seconds.

Is this normal? Can I avoid the two 'hits' and retrieve paginated items only in one database 'hit'?

This is my code in case requested:

```
paginator = Paginator(tips, PAGE_ITEMS)
items = paginator.page(page_number)
if items:
    offset = items.object_list[0]
else:
    offset = None
```

Comment: No. While the second time the query is `SELECT A FROM B` the first time is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT A FROM B)`. The only difference is the counting of objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but some observations:

- The first query `items = paginator.page(page_number)` is to get count of elements. I see it as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ....`
- The second query is actual evaluation of the queryset (that is passed to pagination) to retrieve the objects. With reference to [when querysets evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), the queryset is evaluated when `bool()` or iterated. So queryset will be evaluated at `if items`. But it will be cached and will not be evaluated again when you iterate over the list in template to list the items.

So there does not seem to be way to optimize this and reduce the queries.

Answer (score 1):

This checks if the whole query has any result. But has a different meaning:

```
if paginator.count:
    ....
```

The paginator always needs to hit the DB twice, but like this:

1. SELECT COUNT(*) .... the result is cached in _count. Have a look at _get_count() in the django source
2. SELECT col1, col2, .... LIMIT N

The same query should not be made twice.